# didUpdatePushCredentials not get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, pushkit

I want to implement VoIP notifications in my iOS application, But the **didUpdatePushCredentials** method never got called, I can't get the device token.

I had implemented APNS in the application, May these two services conflict ?

Here is my AppDelegate codes

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    LOGI(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    //register for voip notifications
    self->pushRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [self->pushRegistry setDelegate:self];
    [self->pushRegistry setDesiredPushTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP]];

    NSLog(@"VoIP push registered");

}

#pragma mark - VoIP push methods

- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type {
    NSLog(@"voip token: %@", credentials.token);
}

- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type {
    NSDictionary *payloadDict = [payload.dictionaryPayload valueForKey:@"aps"];
    NSString *message = (NSString *)[payloadDict valueForKey:@"alert"];

    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.alertBody = [message stringByAppendingString:@" - voip"];
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        localNotification.soundName = @"notes_of_the_optimistic.caf";

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"VoIP notification" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        });
    }


    NSLog(@"incoming voip notfication: %@", payload.dictionaryPayload);
}

- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didInvalidatePushTokenForType:(NSString *)type {
    NSLog(@"Voip token invalidate");
}
```

- I enabled remote notifications, Certificate and provisioning profiles are installed.
- I can push standard notifications using APNS.

Any solution to get it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with Certificates.

Regenerated and reimported certificates and issue fixed.

Comment: @KishanVyas When you create push certificate it needs an certificate, Are you sure you select correct certificate ?

Answer (score 18):

If you're running a newer xcode (I'm on xcode 9) then VOIP is not in the Background section on the Capabilities tab. This will prevent `didUpdatePushCredentials` from being called!

The trick is you have to go in your plist, and in `Required Background Modes` you need to add `App provides Voice over IP services`.

I can't believe Apple has done this to us. I wasted an 8 hour work day looking for this simple fix.

[image]

Comment: I already added this into info.plist file. But still I am getting this.

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to enable:

[image]

P.S. I didn't forget to enable 
[image]
But enabling general pushes was important too. So full code is:

```
import UIKit
import PushKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        voipRegistration()

        return true
    }

    // Register for VoIP notifications
    func voipRegistration() {
        let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
        // Create a push registry object
        let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
        // Set the registry's delegate to self
        voipRegistry.delegate = self
        // Set the push type to VoIP
        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [.voIP]
    }

}

extension AppDelegate: PKPushRegistryDelegate {
    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
        let token = pushCredentials.token.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print("voip token = \(token)")
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {
        print("payload = \(payload.dictionaryPayload)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code and Make sure about following things.

```
**`**// Register for VoIP notifications**`**

- (void) voipRegistration {
    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    // Create a push registry object
    _voipRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue: mainQueue];
    // Set the registry's delegate to self
    [_voipRegistry setDelegate:(id<PKPushRegistryDelegate> _Nullable)self];
    // Set the push type to VoIP
    _voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP];
}
```

Call Below method in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

**Other deleget method as follow**

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials: (PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type {
    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server

    if([credentials.token length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"voip token NULL");
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",credentials.token);
}
```

//Make sure about this in project capabilities

1)Background mode is ON

2)VOIP

3)Background Fetch

4)remotenotification

5) Dont forgot to import delegate

**inside the Background MODE**

Comment: I followed the same steps, and these steps are also mentioned by Sinch. But still facing the same issue.