# Pushkit token not getting in some devices iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pushkit

I have implemented `PushKit`. I've followed these steps:

1.) https://stackoverflow.com/a/38184769/4970453

2.) https://stackoverflow.com/a/28562124

I am able to get `didUpdatePushCredentials` device token.
working in --> iPhone 5s , iPhone6 Plus

`didUpdatePushCredentials` Not working in --> iPhone6 and iPhone7

I am using same cerificates and Build for all devices. Don't know the exact issue. 
If anyone have faced this kind of problem, please share work-arounds.

My code and Certificate Link

code -> https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x2615t7xn8mavs3/AADbX5nBuF5_08YNPX8wI59ga?dl=0

cer -> https://www.dropbox.com/sh/70l4htj1c46emog/AABxBalaoN1JP22dQp8-mNXGa?dl=0

```
 Solution -----> I have changed Bundle identifier And create New certificate with New BundleId.
```

Comment: have you checked internet connection on those devices?

Comment: enable voip settings background mode in project Capabilities and please also check  app push notification settings in device Settings should be enable.

Comment: Changing the bundle identifier does not seem like a solution to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work in all devices when integrated properly. there is nothing changed for any device specific.

You can cross verify your steps.

**Swift**

```
import UIKit
import PushKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,PKPushRegistryDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var isUserHasLoggedInWithApp: Bool = true
    var checkForIncomingCall: Bool = true
    var userIsHolding: Bool = true

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


        if #available(iOS 8.0, *){


            let viewAccept = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            viewAccept.identifier = "VIEW_ACCEPT"
            viewAccept.title = "Accept"
            viewAccept.activationMode = .Foreground
            viewAccept.destructive = false
            viewAccept.authenticationRequired =  false

            let viewDecline = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            viewDecline.identifier = "VIEW_DECLINE"
            viewDecline.title = "Decline"
            viewDecline.activationMode = .Background
            viewDecline.destructive = true
            viewDecline.authenticationRequired = false

            let INCOMINGCALL_CATEGORY = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
            INCOMINGCALL_CATEGORY.identifier = "INCOMINGCALL_CATEGORY"
            INCOMINGCALL_CATEGORY.setActions([viewAccept,viewDecline], forContext: .Default)

            if application.respondsToSelector("isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications")
            {
                let categories = NSSet(array: [INCOMINGCALL_CATEGORY])
                let types:UIUserNotificationType = ([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])

                let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: categories as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)

                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }

        }
        else{
            let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        }


        self.PushKitRegistration()

    return true
    }
    //MARK: - PushKitRegistration

    func PushKitRegistration()
    {

        let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
        // Create a push registry object
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {

        let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)

        // Set the registry's delegate to self

        voipRegistry.delegate = self

        // Set the push type to VoIP

        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]

        } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        }


    }


    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
        // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server

        let hexString : String = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(credentials.token.bytes),
        count: credentials.token.length).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")

        print(hexString)


    }


    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {

        // Process the received push

        // Below process is specific to schedule local notification once pushkit payload received

        var arrTemp = [NSObject : AnyObject]()
        arrTemp = payload.dictionaryPayload

        let dict : Dictionary <String, AnyObject> = arrTemp["aps"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>


        if isUserHasLoggedInWithApp // Check this flag then only proceed
        {

            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Background || UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive
            {

                if checkForIncomingCall // Check this flag to know incoming call or something else
                {

                    var strTitle : String = dict["alertTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                    let strBody : String = dict["alertBody"] as? String ?? ""
                    strTitle = strTitle + "\n" + strBody

                    let notificationIncomingCall = UILocalNotification()

                    notificationIncomingCall.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
                    notificationIncomingCall.alertBody =  strTitle
                    notificationIncomingCall.alertAction = "Open"
                    notificationIncomingCall.soundName = "SoundFile.mp3"
                    notificationIncomingCall.category = dict["category"] as? String ?? ""

                    //"As per payload you receive"
                    notificationIncomingCall.userInfo = ["key1": "Value1"  ,"key2": "Value2" ]


                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notificationIncomingCall)

                }
                else
                {
                    //  something else
                }

            }
        }


    }

    //MARK: - Local Notification Methods

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification){

        // Your interactive local notification events will be called at this place

    }


}
```

---

**Objective C**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <PushKit/PushKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,PKPushRegistryDelegate>
{
    PKPushRegistry *pushRegistry;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

---

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    pushRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    pushRegistry.delegate = self;
    pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP];

    return YES;
}

#define PushKit Delegate Methods

- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type{
    if([credentials.token length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"voip token NULL");
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"PushCredentials: %@", credentials.token);
}

- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload");
}
```

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

**Updated answer**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKYW5PZE1aN2pObW8/view?usp=sharing

**Updated answer**

Below are some trouble shooting option.

(1) Change com identifier and try again

(2) Keep puhkit code in app delegeate

I guess, you can change your bundle identifier and try again, it has to be work with all devices.

Comment: You can zip your project, only part with VOIP code and provide drive URL in your question, So anyone can download find out problem and solution.

Comment: Why dont you keep pushRegistry object in .h file ? Also why not in AppDelegate ? Any reason ?

Comment: Check my updated answer, i did some change in your code, download this zip and check.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in the certificates page you have the push notifications enabled in the App ID. 
Also try using a 3G/4G connection. Network configuration may be not letting the device to obtain the token.

Answer (score 0):

For `PushKit` to work properly, here are steps we need to follow:

1. Enable Push Notifications in project Capabilities
2. Enable Remote Notifications in Background Modes
3. Connect device to internet
4. Allow app to receive push notifications

Please refer to [this step-by-step tutorial](http://pierremarcairoldi.com/ios-8-voip-notifications/).

---

As it is happening for some devices only, may 3rd and 4th steps are responsible.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wasn't receiving the VoIP token in some of my devices. A HARD RESET of those devices fixed my issue.