# iOS Pushkit not generating voip push token in testFlight

Tags: ios, cordova, pushkit

I'm using `cordova` and have integrated `pushkit` voip notifications using this [plugin.](https://github.com/akilude/cordova-plugin-voippush) It works fine in development, but **on TestFlight the push tokens are not being generated.**

This is for generating the token only. I have tried the other solutions found in similar questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099280/didupdatepushcredentials-not-get-called?noredirect=1&lq=1).

**All the permissions and certificates are the same for both debug and release build**

- Cordova 9
- Cordova ios 5.1.1
- Xcode 10.2

Testing on an `iPhone X` running iOS 13.2

EDIT: I weirdly started working when the certificates where regenerated twice.

Comment: How are you configuring the provider for this plugin? Also what Push Notification provider are you using? It seems that Firebase does not support Voip Push notifications (as of September 2020)

Comment: @AleksandarT , After i regenerated the push certificates twice from apple developers site,  it started working. I am using APNs not firebase.

Comment: is there an example on how to configure APN's? Because in the plugin i only see usage.

Comment: You can follow this link https://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/create-native-ios-app-can-receive-voip-push-notifications/  in the "Generating a VoIP push certificate" section , choose push "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)" certificate as it includes all apns functionality - test , production and voip certificates in one.